# "General error mounting filesystems" even after BootRepair

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, bootrepair

Upgrading an Ubuntu to Raring Ringtail did not work properly and, now, the machine displays the screen "Ubuntu 13.04" and a few seconds after a text console with:

```
General errors mouting filesystems.
A maintenance shell will now be started.
CONTROL-D will terminate the shell and reboot the system.
```

fsck and mount -a show that the two partitions sda1 and sda6 are OK and can be mounted. (Ubuntu is alone on the disk, no Windows)

I made a BootRepair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair CD, started on it, choosed "32bits session" then "Recommended repair", after a few minutes, the program tells me "Boot successfully repaired" and creates the report in http://paste2.org/E10Cj3VP

But, at the next boot, the problem is exactly the same ("General
errors mouting filesystems."). What can I try now?

I noticed these two questions where the error message is the same but the rest of the story seems quite different : [Ubuntu: "General error mounting filesystems" during boot](https://superuser.com/questions/292787/ubuntu-general-error-mounting-filesystems-during-boot) and 
[Ubuntu: "General error mounting filesystems" during boot](https://superuser.com/questions/292787/ubuntu-general-error-mounting-filesystems-during-boot)

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks to Cédric Dupont on an Ubuntu users' mailing list, here is the solution which worked:

1. Boot on a install CD
2. mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
3. chroot /mnt
4. aptitude update
5. aptitude dist-upgrade

Apparently, the upgrade to the new system was not completed (Cédric noted that the kernel in the report was 3.5 while Ubuntu Raring Ringtail uses 3.8). aptitude was enough to complete it properly.

A few details: in order to use /dev/sda1 as my new root file system, I also had to mount /dev/pts and /run and /run/lock, and to create special node for the root partitipn ('cd /dev; mknod sda1 b 8 1')